# Where can I look for Bash for Windows 10 changelogs?

Tags: 14.04, bash, windows

I was told from people who uses Windows 10 to come here and ask for changelogs made for Windows Subsystem for Linux. This component is made by Canonical, with an Ubuntu distro integrated with Windows 10.

Where exactly can I look up Bash for Windows 10 changelogs, including small detailed changelogs and minor updates?

It's even wonderful if there's a link to Canonical's webpage showing all of the small detailed changelogs.

Thanks in advance. If I'm wrong, please correct me. This is a brand new feature for me, so I'm learning as I go.

Comment: Windows Subsystem  for Linux is made by Microsoft and provided by it. as such, this question is Off-topic on AskUbuntu.com

Comment: However, You can check the release notes of WSL here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/release_notes?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: @AnwarShah But it said it was made by Canonical, and there were updated packages from Canonical installed to the WSL. I was told the changelogs for those packages are found from Canonical. The release notes from Microsoft gives nothing about the incremental updates installed via `sudo apt-get update`.

Comment: For instance, why is this removed? http://imgur.com/4GM9At6.png

Comment: @Zanna I've already set it up, but that was after I have finished updating and upgrading the Ubuntu. Is it possible to see previous changelogs?

Comment: @Zanna So, there's no way for WSL users to check on previous changelogs?

Comment: There might be, I just don't know what it is... [changelogs are here](http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/) (as mentioned in my deleted answer)

Comment: @Zanna I didn't noticed you deleted your answer. Thanks anyway for the help.

Comment: @tom_mai78101: Microsoft makes WSL which runs an Ubuntu distro created by Canonical. The Ubuntu distro is currently exactly the same as a standard Ubuntu cloud image. If you `apt-get update`, packages are updated in exactly the same way as when you run Ubuntu natively on a machine or in a VM - there are no WSL-specific packages or updates applied..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summary release notes are stored here for most of the publicly released Windows 10 Insiders builds:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/release_notes

PS: While, yes, the WSL is a Windows 10 feature, we do run a genuine, unmodified, Ubuntu user-land distro provided by our great partners at Canonical. As such, we are happy to help support Ubuntu questions here on AskUbuntu, along with WSL-specific issues on [our GitHub](https://aka.ms/winbashgithub) or feature asks on [our UserVoice](https://aka.ms/winbashuv).